# LoginView Control Rendering

Tags: asp.net, webforms, bootstrap-4

See [LoginView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview(v=vs.110).aspx) for more infor in the control I am talking about.

Using Bootstrap 3, I don't have an issue because the dropdown menu of the navbar uses ul li, so it would be:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" bla bla bla>Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

but in Bootstrap 4:

```
<a class="dropdown-item">
  LoginView Markup Here
</a>
```

When the bootstrap 4 code renders it creates a nested a tag

```
<a class="dropdown-item">
  <a LoginView Link Rendered Here</a>
</a>
```

Obviously, pressing CTRL + U in the browser shows it doesn't like it (in red), yet I still wish to use this control.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if I understood  your question correctly or not - did you mean LoginView control generated additional <a> tag if you use bootstrap 4? I personally don't believe the issue is due to changing of the bootstrap version though.

Comment: You misunderstand. In Bootstrap 3.3.7 a navbar dropdown uses a UL LI to hold menu items. In Bootstrap 4 they don't use UL LI but a tags. The ASP.NET control renders as an a tag so when rendered you have an a tag for the menu but inside the a tag is another a tag (the rendered login control (see my when bootstrap 4 code renders...)) and nesting an a tag inside another a tag is a no-no. I tried surrounding the a tag with a p tag